# debugger-linecache install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i try to install the  debugger-linecache gem , but i got the following error,

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
....
ERROR:  Error installing debugger-linecache:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- debugger/ruby_core_source (LoadError)
        from extconf.rb:2


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
```

i have already done:

```
sudo gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
```

Comment: I remember I had a problem with this gem before... Try installing another version: `gem install debugger-linecache -v 1.1.0`.

Comment: this has the same result

Comment: I'm having the same issue with no solution, if anyone else has any suggestions, please post them!

Answer (score 3):

i found the problem to be that since i am on fedora , i am using ruby 1.8.3 and that seems to be problem. now upgraded to ruby 1.9.3, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the dependency first:

```
gem install debugger-linecache --version 1.1.2
```

After that, I ran the `bundle install` command and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

What dannynjust said, and:

`git clone git://github.com/cldwalker/debugger-ruby_core_source.git &&
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.7 &&
sudo mv debugger-ruby_core_source /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.7`